# How to load / unload ApplicationInsights

Tags: reactjs, appinsights, applicationinsights-react-js

I am using [ApplicationInsight](https://github.com/microsoft/applicationinsights-react-js) as a ReactPlugin in a react nextjs application.

```
"@microsoft/applicationinsights-react-js": "^17.0.0",
"@microsoft/applicationinsights-web": "^3.0.2",
```

I want the user to be able to enabled / disable application insights due to privacy settings. I enable / load the plugin using `AppInsights.loadAppInsights()` and disable it by calling `await AppInsights.unload()`. When unloading i also delete the ai cookies since unloading does not do this (only ai_authUser is cleared by calling `clearUserSession()`.

The problem is that the second load attempt throws an exception which basically says you cant load a second time.

```
Error: Core cannot be initialized more than once
    throwError throw.js:14
    _DynamicConstants__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__._DYN_INITIALIZE AppInsightsCore.js:215
    loadAppInsights AISku.js:177
    doPerf PerfManager.js:183
    loadAppInsights AISku.js:175
```

Does somebody know what would be the right approach to enable/disable AppInsights? Is there another intended way than load/unload. Thanks for your insights ;)